# getSelectedItemPosition android

Tags: android, arrays

I have been racking my brain trying to figure out why this won't work. I need to return the index of a selected item in a spinner (4 spinners actually but can't even get one to work).

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.agcinstruments.lab41.MainActivity"
android:background="@color/Navy">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/resistor2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/resistor2"/>


<TextView
    android:background="@color/Navy"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:background="@color/Navy"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/q"
    android:background="@color/Navy"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="208dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:background="@color/Navy"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="257dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="94dp"
    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/resistor2"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:entries="@array/color_array1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner2"
    android:layout_below="@id/resistor2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Spinner1"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:entries="@array/color_array2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@id/resistor2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Spinner2"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:entries="@array/color_array3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner4"
    android:layout_below="@id/resistor2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Spinner3"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:entries="@array/color_array4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Spinner4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    android:onClick="onClickCalculate"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultText"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Red"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/White" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tolerance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/Red"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ohm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/Red"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the java code

```
package com.agcinstruments.lab41;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.server.converter.StringToIntConverter;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




public Spinner Spinner1;
public Spinner Spinner2;
public Spinner Spinner3;
public Spinner Spinner4;
int value = 0 ;
int position = 0 ;

TextView resultText;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);


    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

public void onClickCalculate(View view) {


   position = Spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition(); // This is the problem.I suspect the adaptor is not working.
    value = position * 10;
    resultText.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    //resultText.setBackgroundColor()

}

public void resistorValue2(View view) {
    value = value + (1);
}

public void resistorMultiplier(View view) {
    value = value + (1);
}

public void resistorTolerance(View view) {
    value = value + (1);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.agcinstruments.lab41/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.agcinstruments.lab41/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}
```

}

This is the strings.xml file i use to populate the array.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">lab4.1</string>

<string name="calculate">CALCULATE</string>

<string-array name="color_array1">
    <item>BLACK</item>
    <item>BROWN</item>
    <item>RED</item>
    <item>ORANGE</item>
    <item>YELLOW</item>
    <item>GREEN</item>
    <item>BLUE</item>
    <item>PURPLE</item>
    <item>GREY</item>
    <item>WHITE</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="color_array2">
    <item>BLACK</item>
    <item>BROWN</item>
    <item>RED</item>
    <item>ORANGE</item>
    <item>YELLOW</item>
    <item>GREEN</item>
    <item>BLUE</item>
    <item>PURPLE</item>
    <item>GREY</item>
    <item>WHITE</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="color_array3">
    <item>BLACK</item>
    <item>BROWN</item>
    <item>RED</item>
    <item>ORANGE</item>
    <item>YELLOW</item>
    <item>GREEN</item>
    <item>BLUE</item>
    <item>PURPLE</item>
    <item>GREY</item>
    <item>WHITE</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="color_array4">
    <item>BLACK</item>
    <item>BROWN</item>
    <item>RED</item>
    <item>ORANGE</item>
    <item>YELLOW</item>
    <item>GREEN</item>
    <item>BLUE</item>
    <item>PURPLE</item>
    <item>GREY</item>
    <item>WHITE</item>
</string-array>
```

I am do not know a lot of JAVA this is a stumbling block on my road to enlightnment hopefully. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent hours trying to figure out a solution.

Comment: What is the error exactly? Position returned is wrong? Or it is a constant value?

Comment: `Spinner2` is null (no initialization) also you are not adding any data to it. Solve it.

Comment: When I press the calculate button the APP crashes. @GuilhermeP . The problem is when I call the getSelectedItemPosition this crashes the APP.